# Stop jenkin's email notification

Tags: jenkins

I am noticing a strange behavior and want to see if you guys have any suggestion for me. We have three Jenkins instances running: 
1 X Production 
2 X QA

We have email-ext plugin installed as well which we use for sending emails. What we are trying to achieve is stop email generation from our QA servers, but we are unable to do so. 
At present , we cannot change the configuration since we have a cron that syncs its from prod.  So we cannot specify something absurd in the host section of manage-jenkins. 
We were under the impression that Jenkins would use service such as Sendmail/Postfix on the host to send emails but seems to be incorrect.

We disabled Email servers(sendmail/postfix)
Renamed javamail.jar to javamail.jar.bak

But we still keep getting notifications about build failures. Is there any know mechanism by which we can stop these notifications apart from changing configuration?

Comment: "Is there any way to stop email without changing configuration?" Think about it... No. You can "break" it though: you can block email ports on the machine that is running your QA instances. You can also configure your office email spam filter to block emails originating from the IP of the QA instances.

Comment: Well it's quite strange that we have stopped mail services running on the server and if I test email sending from the UI, it fails. But seems like email-ext plugin still manages to over write this and send email.                               Failed to send out e-mail

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: null, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really an answer to the problem above but a workaround. Added junk entries in /etc/hosts file against the smtp host

```
0.0.0.0 uksmtp.xyz.com
```

Post this, Jenkins is unable to send emails under any circumstance.

Comment: This answer made me laugh, cool!

Comment: me too looking back it now :-)